# xorg get windows visible stack (active, behind the active, behind again...)

Tags: xorg

thanks to the excellent wmctrl (http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/)
it was easy for me to retrieve the C code needed to list the visible windows.

what I still need though is to obtain the information about what is the active
window, what is behind the active window, what behind again then...
Does anybody know how I can obtain this information?

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with the `xwininfo` command and see if it includes an option that does what you want. If that's the case, take a look at its source code:

- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xwininfo/tree/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, xwininfo seems to only indicate if the window is mapped or not. My need is mainly to know, from the list of windows, which one is just behind the focused window (which hosts a virtual keyboard).